# Ionic v1: ion-slides event not firing

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides, ion-slide-box

I am using Ionic 1.3.3. I want to add an action event to the slides, but the event doesn't fire at all. Nothing is appearing in the console for the following:

template:

```
<ion-slides options="options" slider="data.slider">
  <ion-slide-page ng-repeat="profile in home.profiles">
    <div class="card image">
      <div id="container-{{profile.$id}}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h2>{{profile.displayName}}, {{profile.age}} (<i class="ion-heart"></i> {{profile.stars}})</h2>
    </div>
  </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

controller:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function (Auth, $ionicLoading, $scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

  var home = this;

  $scope.options = {
    loop: false,
    speed: 800,
    pagination: false,
  };

  $scope.$on('$ionicSlides.sliderInitialized', function (event, data) {
    // data.slider is the instance of Swiper
    console.log('initialized');
    $scope.slider = data.slider;
  });

  $scope.$on('$ionicSlides.slideChangeStart', function (event, data) {
    console.log('Slide change is beginning');
  });

  $scope.$on('$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd', function (event, data) {
    // note: the indexes are 0-based
    console.log('Slide change ended');
    $scope.activeIndex = data.slider.activeIndex;
    $scope.previousIndex = data.slider.previousIndex;
  });

});
```

I copy-pasted most of this from the ionic v1 docs. What am I missing?

Comment: *initialized* working for me. it is not working for you?

Comment: No, doesn't work for me.

Comment: Then something wrong in other code